# How viewport render animation is saved in 3.5?

Tags: animation

How viewport render animation is saved in 3.5?

Created a folder on desktop. In the output setting given path to the folder, FFmpeg, Encoding MP4, video H.264,

I have a small animation of 50 frames.

Under view -> viewport render animation. 50 frames animation finish.

A video file created to given path of 2 second but there is black screen only without any animation in it.

why there is no animation footage in that render.

Any suggestion or help whats going wrong? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Hello, hard to guess without your file, could you share it (make it as simple as possible)?